# Effects of moving an existing Windows install from one SSD to another?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, data-migration

I'm installing a new Samsung EVO 970 drive in my desktop later today, planning on using CloneZilla to move my existing windows 10 installation from my older EVO 850 to the new drive. I will do this by copying the entire 850 drive to the 970 and then resizing the partition afterwards.

**Are there any possible negative effects to this compared to a fresh installation?**

I remember there being a bit of a hassle when doing the same procedure from HDD to SSD, because of how they were two completely different technologies or something like that and I was wondering if the same goes if going from SSD to SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, most likely Windows won't care at all.

However, if you are using an UEFI system, the firmware's built-in boot menu has references to the EFI system partition's GUID (not the one stored within the filesystem, but the 'partuuid' stored within the GPT partition table). CloneZilla will probably do the right thing here, but have a Windows installer handy in case you need to re-run `bcdboot`.

> I remember there being a bit of a hassle when doing the same procedure from HDD to SSD, because of how they were two completely different technologies

The most common problem isn't with moving from HDD to SSD, but with moving to a differently attached disk (e.g. from SATA AHCI to NVMe, as well as from SATA legacy IDE to SATA AHCI).

Windows doesn't mind this move as long as the new driver is marked to start on early boot before doing so, but *by default* it only loads the driver that was detected during installation. (Other drivers are of course available for data disks, but they aren't loaded early enough to boot the actual OS.)

On current Windows 10, the built-in NVMe driver is called "StorNvme", so you would need to configure it to start on boot using:

```
sc config stornvme start= boot
```

Another problem is with moving from a disk that provides 512-byte logical sectors to a disk that provides 4096-byte sectors or vice versa. This "4K" or "AF" is mostly an HDD thing and with SSDs it seems to be an arbitrary choice, with 512B still being the usual size. But if the disks differ, I think CloneZilla is able to deal with it anyway, as it makes per-partition and not whole-disk images.

Comment: "SATA AHCI to NVMe" is essentially what I will be doing since the 970 is NVMe and the 850 is SATA. Do I have to "tell" Windows to load a specific driver for this or will Windows take care of that?

Comment: Yeah, you have to use `sc config stornvme start= boot`. If Windows was installed on SATA AHCI, by default only storahci (or IRST) is marked to load on boot, and the rest only loads during the main phase.

Comment: and am I correct in assuming that I have to run that command from within Windows while still running off the 850? Or will I have to do that using the recovery environment?

Comment: You should run it while still running from the original disk, immediately before cloning. (After doing this, go immediately to CloneZilla and avoid rebooting back into the original disk, and if you do, always re-apply this setting.)

Answer (score 2):

Generally the idea «copying the entire 850 drive to the 970 and then resizing» is solid. If CloneZilla clones GUIDs of GPT partitions as is, it will work fine (I haven't touch CloneZilla yet).

Are you going to resize using Disk Management? Then it's fine. If you're going to use something else, make sure the software you use will take care to align partitions/clusters to SSD blocks.

> Are there any possible negative effects to this compared to a fresh installation?

there are some side-effects caused by resizing partitions (like MFT fragmentation), however it will barely have any effect on SSD, since even with HDD it's negligible.

> I remember there being a bit of a hassle when doing the same procedure from HDD to SSD, because of how they were two completely different technologies or something like that and I was wondering if the same goes if going from SSD to SSD.

I've cloned many HDDs to SSDs in the past, and haven't met really any problems on modern systems, aside from partition GUID updating and need for corresponding BCD updates. However, if you're cloning disk as a whole and the software leaves GUIDs as is, BCD will not need updates and will work fine.
When cloning older systems, up to Windows XP, there was a trouble of partition alignment, but [since Windows Vista](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/09/26/alignment-changes-in-windows-2008-and-2008-r2/), it's not longer an issue.

Comment: I'll probably do the resizing using GParted off a live-usb stick, that program has always served me well.

Comment: What do you mean by "MBR fragmentation"? MFT fragmentation?

Comment: @grawity you're right, I've corrected my answer